# Playing Multiple Sounds at once Java

Tags: java, audio

I've been trying to play multiple sounds at once within Java for a little bit now, I have no problem with playing 1 sound at a single time, but if I try to play like 3 at a time, it will only play 1 sound (I hope this makes sense)

Here is my code:

```
public static void play(String file) {
        try {
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(file)));
            clip.start();

            while (!clip.isRunning())
                Thread.sleep(10);
            while (clip.isRunning())
                Thread.sleep(10);

            clip.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

An example of how I use this method:

```
AudioPlayer.play("sound1.wav");
```

When I also want to be able to do this

```
AudioPlayer.play("sound1.wav");
AudioPlayer.play("sound2.wav");
AudioPlayer.play("sound3.wav");
```

Also, not important but it would also be nice to do something like this as well:

```
AudioPlayer.getPlayingSound("sound1.wav").setVolume(-0.85f);
```

Comment: Your `while` loops are the cause of your problem.  Their whole purpose is to prevent the method from returning until the sound finishes.

Answer (score 1):

To play a clip you should follow this code from a java documentation:

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

    public class LoopSound {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL(
            "http://pscode.org/media/leftright.wav");
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        // getAudioInputStream() also accepts a File or InputStream
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.
            getAudioInputStream( url );
        clip.open(ais);
        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // A GUI element to prevent the Clip's daemon Thread
                // from terminating at the end of the main()
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Close to exit!");
            }
        });
    }}
```

and since you want to play clips simultaneously, you can try doing this:

```
  import java.net.URL;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.sound.sampled.*;

    public class LoopSounds {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL(
            "http://pscode.org/media/leftright.wav");
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.
            getAudioInputStream( url );
        clip.open(ais);

        URL url2 = new URL(
            "http://pscode.org/media/100_2817-linear.wav");
        Clip clip2 = AudioSystem.getClip();
        AudioInputStream ais2 = AudioSystem.
            getAudioInputStream( url2 );
        clip2.open(ais2);

        // loop continuously
        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        clip2.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // A GUI element to prevent the Clip's daemon Thread
                // from terminating at the end of the main()
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Close to exit!");
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try to use multithreading to play multiple sounds at same time.