# Flutter - Can we play one sound file on left ear and another sound file on right ear simultaneously?

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, mobile, mobile-application

I am a beginner in Flutter. I got a small requirement for one ios mobile app.

I need to play 2 different sounds simultaneously

I need to manage the volumes of both sounds separately.

I need to play one sound file on left ear and another sound file on right ear simultaneously

```
For ex:

i) Sound file 1 on left ear, Sound file 2 on Right ear

ii) Sound file 1 on right ear, Sound file 2 on left ear

iii) Both sound files play in left ear

iv) Both sound files play in right ear
```

Is this possible? If yes, Can you please send me any plugin or Code?

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: It seems you need to access native features because you are required to configure sound setting

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40153779/playing-multiple-sounds-at-once-java

Comment: try https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers. from document, it seems to support both simultaneous audio play and a have toggle method player.earpieceOrSpeakersToggle() to switch earpiece or speakers.